# Ironpython missing stack frames if executed in scope

Tags: python, unity-game-engine, ironpython

If I execute this code:

```
    var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
    ScriptScope sc = engine.CreateScope ();
    var ss = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString ("\ndef f():\n    raise Exception('hello generator')\n    yield 42\n\ndef g():\n    f().next()\n\ng()\n", "a.py");

    try {
        ss.Execute();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log(engine.GetService<ExceptionOperations>().FormatException(e));
    }
```

I get stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 7, in g
  File "a.py", line 3, in f
Exception: hello generator
```

But when I execute it in scope:

```
    var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
    ScriptScope sc = engine.CreateScope ();
    var ss = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString ("\ndef f():\n    raise Exception('hello generator')\n    yield 42\n\ndef g():\n    f().next()\n\ng()\n", "a.py");

    try {
        ss.Execute(sc);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log(engine.GetService<ExceptionOperations>().FormatException(e));
    }
```

I get traceback with missing stack trace info...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
Exception: hello generator
```

Why? How can I make it work?

Edit: After testing out, it seems that problem is only present in Unity...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently whole exception handling is broken with Unity, Mono 2 and IronPython 2.6.2. I am posting here in case someone is searching for working solution what worked for me:

```
        List<DynamicStackFrame> frames = ExceptionHelpers.AssociateDynamicStackFrames (e);
        if (frames == null)
            frames = new List<DynamicStackFrame> ();

        String text = "Traceback (most recent call first):\n";
        foreach (DynamicStackFrame frame in frames) {
            text += " File \"" + frame.GetFileName () + "\", line " + frame.GetFileLineNumber () + ", in " + frame.GetMethodName () + "\n";
        }
        text += "Exception: " + e.Message;
        Debug.Log (text);
        frames.Clear ();
        ExceptionHelpers.ClearDynamicStackFrames (e);
```